# Azure - ARM Template deployment

Tags: azure, devops, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to automate some deployments of Resources in Azure. To get the templates, I go to the resource in Azure and select 'Export Template' to get the relevant JSON files. I then try to deploy these into a new environment by running:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group test-rg --template-file arm_templates\test-rg\template.json --mode=Complete
```

This seems to work fine, the error I am getting when deploying these is:

```
[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"PropertyIsReadonly\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The property 'provisioningState' is readonly.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

This is because when exporting my templates, there is a filed called **provisioningState** which is set to "Succeeded". Is there a way I can ignore these readOnly fields when deploying these templates instead of having to manually remove them from the template JSON's?

example ARM template:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/privateEndpointConnections",
      "apiVersion": "2021-10-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('accounts_test-cs-_aue_cscv03_dev_name'), '/', parameters('accounts_test-cs_cscv03_dev_name'), '.300a127f-60fa-4806-99999999999')]",
      "location": "australiaeast",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts', parameters('accounts_test-cs_aue_cscv03_dev_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "privateEndpoint": {},
        "groupIds": ["account"],
        "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
          "status": "Approved",
          "description": "Approved",
          "actionsRequired": "None"
        },
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
      }
    },
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you please add arm template that you are trying to deploy

Comment: @RithwikBojja-MT Added to original question - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to ignore it. Proper JSON for ARM for this type is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.cognitiveservices/accounts/privateendpointconnections?tabs=json

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/privateEndpointConnections",
  "apiVersion": "2021-10-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "properties": {
    "groupIds": [ "string" ],
    "privateEndpoint": {},
    "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
      "actionsRequired": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "status": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So the standard approach to creating these ARM configs is to not just export from existing resources and use across environments? Instead they should be created manually? Otherwise I would have to make these changes everytime I update a resource and download a new template.

Comment: @adan11 It's more reliable to save a single working template with anything which can vary (e.g. names, SKUs) replaced with parameters. You can base this on an exported template, but you will need to carefully edit it to get the settings exactly right. After you've got this template ready and stable, you supply values for each parameter when you deploy to a new environment.